# Tax Planning Capital Gains

Tags: income-tax, canada, capital-gains-tax

Tax Planning - I'm retired and want to take my income as close as possible to $45,916.00 using Stock Capital Gains to maintain the lowest tax bracket of 15% and do the same for years to come as I have exceptional capital gains.

Should I calculate this capital gain income dollar for dollar, or divide the total capital gain by two, as you only pay tax on 50% of your capital gain...?

My fear is that the dollar for dollar calculation will take my income above the $45,916.00 and into the next tax bracket which is 25% tax?? Thank You!

Comment: Where do you live? Tax questions require a jurisdiction. Looks like.. Canada?

Comment: General comment, without knowing jurisdiction: typically tax brackets apply to income *above* that bracket. ie: assuming your numbers are correct, your first 45,916 would be taxed at 15%, and every dollary *above* 45,916 would be taxed at 25%.

Comment: If you're in the US (and under the current tax code), wouldn't most of the capital gains be taxed at 0%, as long as your other income keeps you in the 15% or under brackets?

Comment: I happen to have recognized the numbers as Canadian. ([see here](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/frequently-asked-questions-individuals/canadian-income-tax-rates-individuals-current-previous-years.html))